# Aligning checkboxInput along with the box title in shiny

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I have a shiny application, where in I am trying to provide a checkbox on top of a graph for the user to select.  Currently, the check box is rendered below the title, whereas I want the title on the left hand side and the check box on the right hand side in the same line.  I am sure it can be achieved through recoding CSS, but don't know how.  The current code looks as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
        title = "MODULE",titleWidth = 225
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
        width = 225,
        sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                    menuItem("TOPLINES", tabName = "tplines", icon = shiny::icon("dashboard"))
        )),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(
                tabName = "tplines",
                fluidRow(
                    box(
                        checkboxInput(inputId = "inventorytop8metrocheck", "Add to reports", value = FALSE),
                        width = 6, status = "info", title = "Inventory information",
                        div(plotlyOutput("inventorytop8metro"), width = "100%", height = "400px", style = "font-size:80%;")
                    )
                    )))))

server <- function(session,input,output){

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are just looking for the standard row partition with `columns`. The title arguement takes any ui elements, so we input a row that is half your original title and half the checkbox input. Thus, they are in line. Of course, the checkbox then has the same style as the title. If you don't want that, you can alter the style by setting a `style` parameter in the checkbox column.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "MODULE",titleWidth = 225
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 225,
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
      menuItem("TOPLINES", tabName = "tplines", icon = shiny::icon("dashboard"))
  )),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tplines",
        fluidRow(
          box(
            width = 6, status = "info", title = fluidRow(
              column(6, "Inventory information"),
              column(6, checkboxInput(inputId = "inventorytop8metrocheck", "Add to reports", value = FALSE))
            ),
            div(plotlyOutput("inventorytop8metro"), width = "100%", height = "400px", style = "font-size:80%;")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(session,input,output){}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification...I never knew that the Title can be split into multiple columns...and you suggestion of newer style arguments helped.